# How can I insert a ringtone in MediaStore when wrapping apk with Mobile Iron?

Tags: android, kotlin, mediastore, ringtone, mobileiron

We're using Mobile Iron to wrap our app.

I'm facing problems while inserting a ringtone in the `MediaStore`.
I've read many questions but none are up-to-date: Indeed, `MediaStorage.Audio.Media.DATA` is deprecated since Android 10 (Q). Moreover, it seems that, searching for a solution, in "Post" Android Q, the content Uri has to be accessed another way.
So I have to separate code for "Pre" and "Post" Android Q.

Here is my code:

```
val collection = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
} else {
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
}

val values = ContentValues()
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, ringtoneName)
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "ringtone.wav"))
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/x-wav")
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true)
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false)
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false)
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false)

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    Log.e("Ringtone", "Android 9 : Extracting file in external Storage")
    extractRingtone(context)
    var file: File? = null
    try {
        file = File(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_RINGTONES)!!.canonicalFile, "ringtone.wav")
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE, file?.length())
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, file?.absolutePath)
}
else
{
    val inputStream = context.resources.openRawResource(R.raw.ringtone)
    val size = inputStream.available()
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE, size)
    inputStream.close()
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_PENDING, true)
}

var newUri: Uri? = null
try {
        newUri = resolver.insert(collection, values)
}
catch (exception: Exception)
{
    Log.e("Ringtone", "Exception while inserting data", exception)
}
```

Then, in "Post" Android Q, I try to insert the ringtone in the content provider using `resolver.openOutputStream(newUri)`, and then, update the ringtone with `MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_PENDING` set to ````false``` but newUri is always null and Exception is never thrown.

The code works correctly when the app isn't wrapped.

Any idea?

Edit: Added `MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_PENDING` value in ContentValues, but it didn't do the trick.

Edit 2: Updated question as we now the problem isn't the code but the wrapping of the app using Mobile Iron.

Comment: Use column IS_PENDING twice.

Comment: Just read some stackoverflow pages tagged `mediastore`.

Comment: Ok, found it. I'll try tomorrow. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you considered SoundPool for playing sounds?
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool
I found it to be very easy, and I have a class that implements sounds easily. If you're interested I can post the code.

Comment: @blackapps Thanks for your help mate, but unfortunately, this didn't do the trick. :( I will edit my code with the added lines.

Comment: @ezaspi The aim here is to set the file as a ringtone for specific contacts. I don't wantt to play it.

Comment: `facing problems while inserting a ringtone in the ContentResolver` No. You try to insert a file in the media store. Try without these other IS_... values.

Comment: @blackapps yes, you're right. I edit my question.

Comment: Tried your code (as Java) and it gives nice uries from .insert() on Android 11.

Comment: @blackapps I forgot to mention that the app is "wrapped" with Mobile Iron. And, you're right, when I don't wrap it, the code works correctly. So the problem comes from the wrapping and not from my code. Thanks for your help, I'll close the subject.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by @blackapps , the code works correctly, indeed. The thing I didn't mention is that the app is "wrapped" using Mobile Iron. When not wrapped, the code works normally and I don't get the error.

Thanks to him, I came to the conclusion that the wrapping of the app causes my problem, as it makes the app sandboxed and apparently denies the write of any file in the phone.

Anyway, this is not a problem with Android nor Kotlin, but with Mobile Iron.

So I updated my question, its tags and its title.